# VS Code, navigate among file symbols

Tags: visual-studio-code, navigation

When you select a symbol in VSCode it highlights (underlines) the symbols in the file.  Is there a command (keyboard shortcut) that is available which I can use to navigate among the occurrences of the symbol in the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the `Go to next symbol highlight` command: `editor.action.wordHighlight.next`. It is bound to <kbd>F7</kbd> by default.

That command jumps to the next highlighted occurrence in the file. <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd> jumps to the previous one

Comment: Fantasitc, exactly what I was looking for.